# set custom node equality comparison in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm using python3 and networkx to construct a graph.  Networkx is really great, but let's say I want to put some nice objects in as nodes.  Here is my object maker (a simple class, for the purposes of demonstration):

```
class DictToObject:
    def __init__(self, dic):
        for key, value in dic.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
```

And then here are some nodes:

```
import networkx

s1 = DictToObject({"name":"sarah", "id":"s"})
s2 = DictToObject({"name":"sarah", "id":"s"})

M = networkx.DiGraph()
M.add_edge(s1, s2)
```

Due to overriding `__eq__`, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "networkxcapabilitytest.py", line 16, in <module>
    M.add_edge(s1, s2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/classes/digraph.py", line 485, in add_edge
    if u not in self.succ:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'DictToObject'
```

This is very upsetting.  Overriding `__eq__` seemed like the "right" way to let networkx identify when two nodes should be considered the "same".  Perhaps I should submit this issue to the networkx developers.  Or perhaps there is a networkx built-in or better way to do this.

Comment: You also need to implement `__hash__`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you think this is unrelated to networkx?

Comment: Yes, the problem is simply that you're trying to put an unhashable object into a data structure that requires hashable objects, therefore you need to implement `__hash__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @jonrsharpe's comment:

```
class DictToObject:
    def __init__(self, dic):
        for key, value in dic.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__dict__.values())
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__.values())

import networkx

s1 = DictToObject({"name":"sarah", "id":"s"})
s2 = DictToObject({"name":"sarah", "id":"s"})

M = networkx.DiGraph()
M.add_edge(s1, s2)

print( M.nodes() )
print( M.edges() )
```

Output:

```
[dict_values(['s', 'sarah'])]
[(dict_values(['s', 'sarah']), dict_values(['s', 'sarah']))]
```

Note that, **there is only one node in the graph now**. Since the `hash()` produces (id's equal) same thing, hence it does not add the second node to the graph.

---

## Edit

As discussed in the comment, a better solution can be provided at the following [link](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/discussions/6742). 
Indeed, the solution proposed before had some problems with the `hash` function and it gives problem in case you want to do `print(M)` or even `nx.draw(M)`.

Then, the improved solution is:

```py
import networkx as nx

class DictToObject:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._data['id'] == other._data['id']

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._data['id'])

s1 = DictToObject({"name":"sarah", "id":"s"})
s2 = DictToObject({"name":"sarah", "id":"s"})

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(s1, s2)

print(G)

nx.draw(G)
```

Comment: So far so good!  Thanks!

Comment: @mareoraft, I tried the solution proposed and there is, in my opinion, a **big problem** with it.
I ended up having a Key Error when I try `networkx.draw(M)` or `print(M)`. Therefore, since I have the same problem to solve, I opened a _discussion on the repository of the library_. The repository's maintainers helped me out, now I have a working solution.

I share with you the [link of the discussion](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/discussions/6742), since I cannot reply under this question anymore :( .

Comment: @AndreP has a good point. The original answer is problematic because the hash function hashes all the dictionary values when it should just hash the id itself.  I would recommend following his link and using the suggested approach there.  Thanks Andre!